# Right view of binary tree without using queue in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

[HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-right-view-binary-tree-2/) is the c++ implementation for right view of binary tree without using queue. When I try to convert it to Java, it is not working. Here is my Java code:

(I think most likely it is because I have not understood the algorithm properly and handling of maxLevel pointers/reference)

```
public static void rightView(TreeNode tNode){
    int maxLevel = 0;
    rViewUtil(tNode, 1,maxLevel);
}

public static void rViewUtil(TreeNode tNode, int level, int maxLevel){
    if(tNode==null)
        return;
    if(maxLevel < level){
        System.out.print(tNode.value + " ");
        maxLevel = level;
    }
    rViewUtil(tNode.right, level+1, maxLevel);
    rViewUtil(tNode.left, level+1, maxLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of @lifus' answer, but avoiding mutable state, you can use the function return to set `maxLevel`

```
public static void rightView(TreeNode tNode){
    int maxLevel = 0;
    rViewUtil(tNode, 1,maxLevel);
}

public static int rViewUtil(TreeNode tNode, int level, int maxLevel){
    if(tNode==null)
        return;
    if(maxLevel < level){
        System.out.print(tNode.value + " ");
        maxLevel = level;
    }
    maxLevel = rViewUtil(tNode.right, level+1, maxLevel);
    maxLevel = rViewUtil(tNode.left, level+1, maxLevel);
    return maxLevel
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I didn't get the problem yet. I am anyway passing updated MaxLevel everytime so what is the problem. I am partially getting it almost there .. stil do not understand how the current code is problem. Can you please please give a example and explain in two lines why my current code is not working (I understand it has do with pass by value thing .. but how ?)

Comment: The problem is you set the value of `maxLevel` inside the function. In C++, both the recursive calls you make and the caller will see the change you make in the memory region `int* maxLevel` points. In your Java translation, only the subsequent recursive calls see the change, not the caller.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Java is [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

i.e. `maxLevel = level;` doesn't affect *other* `maxLevel` values.

In you case, you should remove parameter `maxLevel` and use static variable instead:

```
private static int maxLevel;

public static void rightView(TreeNode tNode){
    maxLevel = 0;
    rViewUtil(tNode, 1);
}

public static void rViewUtil(TreeNode tNode, int level){
    ...
}
```

Note: It's not thread safe

---

Alternatively, you may use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
public static void rightView(TreeNode tNode){
    rViewUtil(tNode, 1, new AtomicInteger());
}

public static void rViewUtil(TreeNode tNode, int level, AtomicInteger maxLevel){
    ...
    if(maxLevel.get() < level){
        ...
        maxLevel.set(level);
    }
}
```

It stores [volatile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) int under the hood.

Note: As @Daniel mentioned, it's in concurrent package and intended for multithreading applications.

---

Another option is to create your "own" [mutable integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25050985/2286990) or reuse [an existing one](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableInt.html).

Comment: @lifus Thanks a lot for replying. I knew this is what the problem is but still I am not able to understand it well. I am still passing maxLevel everytime to the function call, so no matter pass by value or reference ... shouldn't the change reflect in other calls ?? I know it is something simple that I am missing here related to call backs.

Comment: Don't use AtomicInteger, it is meant for concurrent applications, not reference uses.  There is unfortunately no built in mutable Integer object, but you can  create your own easily enough.

Comment: @DavidS Didn't get it.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you. I came across this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Amutableintwrapper.htm ... can you please suggest how to write a easy and less comprehensive mutable integer wrapper ?

Comment: @Daniel I agree, it was just an example that it's possible to avoid shared mutable state.

Comment: Thanks, @lifus. I will never doubt myself again!