# Java: Modifying parameter passed as a Reference

Tags: java, reference

I have to implement an interface method that has the signature like:

```
public int runMethod(final int key, Reference <String> result);
```

I have to update the value of `result` parameter before method returns. For example if the value of `result` was `ABC` when the method was invoked, I need to modify it as `DEF` and return to caller. Can somebody suggest how do I achieve it?

Comment: Could you tell how the class Reference looks like?

Comment: Are you referring to `java.lang.ref.Reference`? If so, this is not what that class is for.

Comment: Yes, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520137/does-java-have-mutable-types-for-integer-float-double-long

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't modify the *variable* that you passed to the method. For example:

```
public int runMethod(final int key, Reference <String> result) {
    result = null; // Only changed the method's version of the variable, and not the variable that was passed to the method
}
...
Reference<String> ref = ...
runMethod(0, ref);
// ref is still what you originally assigned it to
```

However, you can modify the fields and call the methods of the *object* you pass.

```
public int runMethod(final int key, Reference <String> result) {
    result.someField = ...; // Here we are changing the object, which is the same object as what was passed to the method.
}
...
Reference<String> ref = ...
runMethod(0, ref);
// ref.someField has now been changed
```

An alternative would be to change the method's return type to `Reference<String>` and return the updated value.

```
public Reference<String> runMethod(final int key, Reference <String> result) {
    return ...;
}
...
Reference<String> ref = ...
ref = runMethod(0, ref);
// ref is now whatever you returned from the method
```

Comment: More generally, Java always passes by value, either for primitive and refenrene type, more here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: This correctly explains argument passing, but neither the `Reference` interface nor any of the three implementation classes in the standard library provide a mechanism to change what object an instance refers to.  They are not intended for the kind of use the OP seems to be trying to put them to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah, I didn't realise that there was a `Reference`type in the standard library and assumed it was a third-party type.

Comment: He can't change the return type to a type which is not incompatible with the implemented one.

Comment: Well, thank you all. I also thought the 'Reference' was from java.lang.Reference. But on further investigation found that it's from a third party and has an assign method.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill Please check my edit, I simply forgot to change the method's return type in the example code. It was quite late at night.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 unfortunately he coudn't change the return type from `int` to `Reference` because `Reference` type isn't incompatible with 'int`, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill Well obviously it isn't. If the return type *can* be changed then it is a way of achieving what the OP wanted.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 we can change return type for overriden methods to only compatible type and `Reference` isn't compatible with `int`

Comment: @SamTebbs33 the OP said that he must implement an interface which contains that method ;)

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill Yes but if you change the return type of the interface's method, then there won't be a problem!

Comment: @SamTebbs33 of course isn't a problem, but usually you don't change the interface, cause if there's many classes which implement it, it would be a pain to do that, another thing, what if the interface is in a third party library?!!!

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill That's why I first said if you *can*  change the return type, then it is an alternative, if not then don't do it, as I have already said.....

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to pass as reference, here is a tricky way by wrapping it in an array:

```
class TestRef{
  static void func(int[] arr){arr[0] = -arr[0];}
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arrI = new int[1];
    arrI[0] = 250;

    System.out.println(arrI[0]); // 250
    func(arrI);
    System.out.println(arrI[0]); // -250
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In java objects are in effect passed by reference. That is, parameter 'result' within runMethod appears to be exactly the same object as in the caller, not a copy. So, by updating the contents of Reference parameter of runMethod you will be achieving the goal you have described.

However, 'result' itself is not actually a pointer to the caller's passed variable so it is not possible to overwrite the object itself, only update it's contents.

Comment: In Java, all arguments are passed by *value*.  This includes references.  In runMethod, `result` is a *copy* of the `Reference` reference that was provided as an argument.  The two are independent references to the same object.

Comment: It would have been straight forward if Java passed parameters by Reference. But it's not.

Comment: OK, according to the Java spec you are correct. But, can you explain this in a simple way which does not just add more confusion to this simple question? The behaviour is that of pass by reference.

Comment: Java is *pass-by-reference* (for non-primitive types) since the same object reference is passed to the method, the method parameters just don't have any link to the actual variables that were passed to the method. Only the contents of the object can be changed, and not the variable being passed itself.

Comment: This is basically a semantic argument and of no help to the question.

Comment: Yeah I want to change the contents

Comment: I do see the distinction, please see amended answer. Basically, calling result.updateSomething() or result.publicProperty = "something" will work as you want but result = null; will not cause the callers variable to become null as the parameter received by runMethod is not a true pointer.