# Why Float and Double wrapper classes are immutable in java?

Tags: java, wrapper, immutability

Byte, Short and Integer maintains a buffer pool values representing -128 to 127. Character pools values representing '\u0000' to '\u007F'.

So that I can understand that why all above wrapper classes are Immutable.

But, Float and Double do not maintain any buffer pool then **what is the purpose of making these classes as Immutable?**

I read it from below link:
https://coderanch.com/t/670745/java/Wrapper-Classes-Immutable

Comment: There's probably a more actual reason, but for me the question one should ask is **why would you make it mutable?**. Just imagine the confusions that would result if you could call `floatVar.setValue(2f)`, and then count on auto-boxing on the following line to use `floatVar` as a primitive parameter (or the reverse, where a `updateMyFloat(Float floatParam)` method calls `floatParam.setValue(3)` and the caller invokes ``updateMyFloat(1.1f)`)...

Comment: @Thilo I don't think this question is duplicate as I am asking about only floating point wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if `Byte`, `Short`, `Character` and `Integer` are immutable, it would be very inconsistent to make `Double` and `Float` mutable.

Mutability also has it's cost - you cannot share the same resource safely between multiple threads. Copying them on demand is very cheap.

I also do not see a use case to make them mutable - if you want to use it as some combined in/out parameter, it's a poor design.

Answer (score 0):

If the standard primitive wrappers were mutable, then you would effectively break the boxing / unboxing feature.

```
 Integer mutable = 1;
 mutable.setValue(2);
 Integer one = 1;
 System.out.println(one);   // Prints '1'?  Or '2'?
```

If you want mutable primitive wrappers, they more or less exist already in the form the Java SE "atomic" classes; i.e. `AtomicBoolean`, `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicLong`.  These have the advantage (but also the cost) of being thread-safe.

Other alternatives include one element arrays, using a 3rd-party alternative such as the Apache Commons `MutableInt` (etcetera) classes ...  or writing your own classes at about 10 lines of code a time.

See also:

- [Does Java have mutable types for Integer, Float, Double, Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520137/does-java-have-mutable-types-for-integer-float-double-long)