# Getting ClassNotFoundException when trying to implement web filter in my JSF app

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a JSF app and for some reasons i need to refresh the page on browser back button.I tried implementing the solution given in  [Force JSF to refresh page / view / form when opened via link or back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101380/force-jsf-to-refresh-page-view-form-when-back-button-is-pressed) by BalusC ,the only difference is that my app runs with servlet version 2.5 so i did the mapping in web.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    
        javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD
        client
    
    
        javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES
        /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
    
    
        com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    
    
        javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE
        Production
    
    
        javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE
        true
    
    
        login.xhtml
    
    
        FacesServlet
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        1
    
    
        FacesServlet
        /faces/
    
    
        *FacesServlet*
        .jsf
    
    
        FacesServlet
        *.faces
    
    
        FacesServlet*
        .xhtml
    
    
        
        SessionUtil
        SessionUtil
        com.gaic.lpsr.utilclasses.SessionUtil
    
    
        SessionUtil
        /SessionUtil

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.gaic.lpsr.utilclasses.NoCacheFilter.java</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cacheFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>

</filter-mapping>
```

My filter class is

```
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (!request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// ...
```

}

I have included the jar servlet-api-2.5.jar.When i try to deploy app in tomcat server(version 6.0.29) i am getting the below error.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter cacheFilter
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gaic.lpsr.utilclasses.NoCacheFilter.java
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Please guide me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did silly mistake in web.xml :).Solved by removing .java extension in filter mapping

```
<filter-class>com.gaic.lpsr.utilclasses.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
```