# Using Method changing a Variable, then unable to assign value to another variable

Tags: java, android

I have a method to change a variable (declared =0) into an integer (eg: 10), then I would like to assign this integer to another variable (int playerOneIcon)

**`SomeActivity`**:

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Integer playerOneIcon= 0, playerIcon = 0;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Button btn_test = findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
    btn_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(ii_PlayerSetting.this, String.valueOf(playerOneIcon), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

ShowPop1(View v) {  }
//Will paste it below

ShowPop2(View v) {  }
//Will paste it below

public void onClick(View v){     }
//Will paste it below

}
```

The "ShowPop1(View v) will run when user clicked on a button, it will call a pop up dialog, hence calling the onClick() within:

**`ShowPop1(View v)`**

```
ShowPop1(View v) {
playerIcon = playerOneIcon;

ChangeHeadDialog.setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);

onClick(v);

playerOneIcon = playerIcon;
}
```

**`ShowPop2(View v)`**

```
ShowPop2(View v) {
playerIcon = playerTwoIcon;

ChangeHeadDialog.setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);

onClick(v);

playerTwoIcon = playerIcon;
}
```

**`onClick(v)`**

```
onClick(v){
playerIcon = 10;
ChangeHeadDialog.dismiss();
//if i put "playerOneIcon = playerIcon;" here, it will work, but I can't since it may be playerTwoIcon that should assign instead

}
```

Then when I pressed the btn_test, result is 0,. Please help, thanks you so much!

Comment: Where are you printing "playerOneIcon"?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26315827/5015207) to the other post may be what you're looking for

Comment: @PrashanthVerma Edited the question for better understanding, thanks!

Comment: are you calling Toast before or after the showPop1()?. Can you please put the whole code?

Comment: @PrashanthVerma after the ShowPop1(). Oh which part you want to know more? I can try but it would be an enormous line of codes I am afraid...

Comment: Can i know why are using "break" in onClick()?

Comment: @PrashanthVerma Oh my bad, it was in a switch statement that's why the break. But it is not relevant to the question, i will edit it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding one more variable in showpop1() & showPop2(), then running a method inside onClick().

> **ShowPop1(View v)**

```
ShowPop1(View v) {
playerIcon = playerOneIcon;

//New Line
String playerSelected = "player1"
//New Line

ChangeHeadDialog.setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);

onClick(v);

}
```

> **ShowPop2(View v)**

```
ShowPop2(View v) {
playerIcon = playerTwoIcon;

//New Line
String playerSelected = "player2"
//New Line

ChangeHeadDialog.setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);

onClick(v);

}
```

> **applyPlayerIconToPlayer(Integer playerIcon)**

```
private void applyPlayerIconToPlayer(Integer playerIcon) {
    switch (playerSelected){
        case "player1":
            playerOneIcon = playerIcon;
            break;
        case "player2":
            playerTwoIcon = playerIcon;
            break;
}}
```

Run applyPlayerIconToPlayer(Integer playerIcon) inside onClick():

```
onClick(v){
playerIcon = 10;
ChangeHeadDialog.dismiss();
applyPlayerIconToPlayer(Integer playerIcon)
}
```

Done!